# SSAS claimsToken is not supported

Tags: active-directory, ssas

I've setup an SSAS server and I've connected it with my active directory server. 
But when I try to login on the ssas server (sql server management studio) using an active directory account I get the following error:

Cannot connect to SQLASServer.

The integrated security 'ClaimsToken' is not supported for native connections. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.AdomdClient)

This error shows up before it actually tries to connect or anything so if I try to login using a bogus username and no password I still get the same error.

When I login to the server with an active directory account and then login on sql server management studio using Windows Authentication it does work without any errors.

Does anybody know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you choose Windows Authentication from the Authentication dropdown. The options that say “Active Directory” are poorly worded as they mean Azure Active Directory and are not appropriate for on premises SSAS.

If that does not solve it provide a screenshot of your connection dialog in SSMS.

Comment: Alright that explains it. I'm not using azure active directory so therefore that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake was that I had chosen Azure Analysis Services from before from the first drop down menu so I was getting this error. Once I changed it to SQL database, the option to connect with Azure Active Directory was available as well as to connect through SQL database credentials. In order to use the Azure Active Directory you need to create an active directory account and set that account as admin on Azure Portal first.