# Trying to connect to SSAS to connect to a PBI workspace in SSMS

Tags: sql, ssms, ssas, xmla

Trying to connect to sql server analysis server for the first time to view datasets under a workspace
but when i'm setting up my connection with `Active Directory - Universal with MFA support` authentification i'm getting the following error message:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to powerbi://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/Test.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The integrated security 'ClaimsToken' is not supported for native connections. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.AdomdClient)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Windows Authentication instead? It looks like you might be having the same issue: [SSAS claimsToken is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887525/ssas-claimstoken-is-not-supported/53977494#53977494)

Comment: I get the following error: The connection string is not valid.

Comment: Which SSMS version are you using?

Comment: i'm running version 17.6.

Comment: You would need SSMS version 18.8 or higher (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-connect-tools)